# From module, use only some components of a derived data type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Consider this simple module:

```
module mod1
implicit none
    type namespace
        integer :: int1
        real    :: real1
    endtype
    type(namespace)        :: namespace1
end module mod1
```

Now I want to import just int1 from this derived datastructure `namspace1`, so as to keep track of what variable came from where.

Following program give an error:

```
program tmp
    use mod1, only: int1 => namespace1%int1
    implicit none
    print *, int1
end program tmp
```

I get the following error

> Error: Syntax error in USE statement at (1)

Is there some way to only use requires components from a derived datatype? or I need to do `use mod1, only: nm => namespace1` followed by `nm%int1` only?

Comment: No, there is no way to use-associate only part of a derived data type as you wish.  If I understood what you are trying to do I might be able to offer a suggestion, but I don't.

Comment: I am collaborating on a Fortran code which have a global variable module, with several arrays, variables and constants; to be used throughout the program. I has hoping to encapsulate all of them under categories, like "flags", "constants", "iofiles" etc. and then each file, i can only import the required variables. this should maintain older files fully functional by just adding one line, whereas i can add new functionality in more cleaner way. ie, there is a variable x in current code and i can do `use global, only: x=>constants%x`, and keep old code functional.

Comment: You can move the various parts into separate modules separated by some logic. It will be much simpler to change the old code, you will just change the name of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Components cannot be selectively USE'd into other scopes.

Components within a type can be made PRIVATE to the defining module and its descendants, but this prevents them from being accessed in all other program units.

Fortran derived types are not suitable as a namespace management prop.